# Changing cursor for ToolBarButton in Windows Forms

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, mouseevent

**please note:**

In this post I am referring to the outdated [`ToolBarButton`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolbarbutton(v=vs.110).aspx) and **not** the [`ToolStripButton`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripbutton(v=vs.110).aspx).

I am implementing a help-feature where you can go into a help mode to display help for certain ui-elements. The cursor should change to `Cursors.Help` once you hover over an element which has such help attached. That works well for most elements, but not for `ToolBarButton`s as it lacks the `.Cursor` property.

What I have been doing so far was:

```
Private Sub EnterHelpMode() 
    helpMode = True
    toolBar.Cursor = Cursor.Help
    ' ... other help-related stuff
End Sub
```

Unfortunately that gives the whole `ToolBar` that help icon. How do I achieve the same behaviour but only for the `ToolBarButton`s? I also tried it with the `MouseEnter` event on the `ToolBar`, but unlike the `ButtonClick` event this one doesn't give me a `ToolBarButtonClickEventArgs` argument, so I can't determine which `ToolBarButton` was hovered (which makes sense, because the source isn't always a `ToolBarButton`, while with the `ButtonClick` it is).

Thanks in advance

Comment: That is not the right way to do it and not the standard way.   The Capture property is the key, set it to *true* when the help button is clicked.  You are now in full control of Cursor.Current and get all the MouseMove events.  Do hit testing to see what control or toolstripitem is being hovered and change Cursor.Current accordingly.  Stop the help mode and display the relevant topic when you get MouseDown.

Comment: thanks, i will see if i can make that work

Comment: @HansPassant I am unable to do the hit testing with a `ToolBarButton` as it lacks a `ClientRectangle` method. Any suggestion on how to do that?

Comment: You have to do this the other way around again.  Use the form's GetChildAtPoint() method to find the control being hovered.  That will return a ToolStrip, now you can use its GetItemAt() method to get the ToolStripItem.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for your effort, but i am not talking about a ToolStrip, but an actual ToolBar: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolbar(v=vs.110).aspx
with actual ToolBarButtons: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolbarbutton(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Oh, yuck.  Well, about the same recipe, test for ToolBar and then iterate its Buttons to hittest against their Rectangle.

Comment: @HansPassant can i ask one last question? I looked into the `Capture ` Property of my form, but it seems like it only catches a single event. how would that help me check if the cursor has moved into a valid `Control` over a longer duration?

Answer (score 0):

Modified to use HelpMode:

```
Dim HelpMode as Boolean = False  ' a global variable

Private Sub tsButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tsbUpdte.Click
    HelpMode = True
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Cross
End Sub


Private Sub HelpForControls_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tsButton1.MouseDown, tsButton2.MouseDown
    If HelpMode = True Then
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default 
        Dim oName as String = CType(Sender, ToolStripButton).Name   ' this works only for ToolStripButtons        
        Call ShowHelp(oName)   ' show some help content using a dedicated sub
        HelpMode = False
        Exit Sub   ' terminate function
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ShowHelp(StrName as String)
    SELECT CASE StrName
       Case "BtnEdit" : MsgBox("This button will allow you to edit selected record.")
       Case "BtnDelete" : MsgBox("This button will allow you to delete selected record.")
    End Select
End Sub
```

You can possibly use also Me.Capture and check what is clicked on (as suggested in comments), but I have no experience with this property.

Comment: I am talking about a `ToolBarButton`. maybe I just don't know how, but they don't let me listen to MouseEnter (i have already tried that) and as I said I can't change their Cursor

Comment: Yes, as suggested, you need to use HelpMode. I will modify my answer, hopefully it will help to direct you...

Comment: of what type is your object `tsButton1`?

Comment: It's Button. So this will work only for Buttons (or 1 set object type), as comment suggests. If you need a mix of objects (i.e. picturebox, button, combobox,...), you will have to expand the logic on the line, where the object name is received (CType(sender,Button).Name). Perhaps there's a metod (I don't know) which can get a Name property regardless object's type... You will need this sub-routine also if you use the other method (.Capture), I think.

Comment: ok, let me clarify it one more time: I have a `ToolBarButton`. That is not the same as a `Button`. This does not work for a `ToolBarButton`, which is the whole point I am trying to make

Comment: Do you mean ToolStripButton? Then replace CType(Sender, Button).Name for CType(Sender, ToolStripButton).Name and it will work, but only for ToolStripButtons. But be aware, this is *target* object, not the button you start the help with! So if you set it the way described above, you can get help for any of the ToolStrip buttons (aka Toolbar icons). Is help for toolbar icons, what you are after?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolbarbutton(v=vs.110).aspx

`ToolBarButton`! it doesnt let me handle any events, because it doesn't inherit from System.Windows.Forms.Control !

Comment: Ahh! *"Although ToolStripButton replaces and extends the ToolBarButton control of previous versions, ToolBarButton is retained for both backward compatibility and future use if you choose."* - this says MS. To be honest, I'm not sure what you can do with TBB, it is not even in the ToolBox in my VisualStudio and I don't even remember seeing it there ever. I wonder, how you got ToolBar into your project...